# How to handle redirects from a reverse-proxied server mapped to a subdirectory in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, redirect

I would like use Nginx as a reverse proxy for an app, which is mapped to a subdirectory of my site.  The app has its own set of locations , and must be able to issue redirects to other locations within the app, but the app is not aware that it is mapped to a subdirectory of the main site.

For example: `https://example.com/app/page1` should be passed to `http://the_app/page1`.  Additionally, if app issues a redirect to `/page2`, then Nginx should modify the location in the response to `https://example.com/app/page2`.

Here is my current configuration:

```
upstream the_app {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

**. . .**

```
rewrite /app /app/ break;
location ~/app(?<app_path>/.*$) {
    proxy_pass http://the_app$app_path;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

This does forward requests to the app with the correct path (e.g. `http://app/page1`), but does not handle redirects correctly.  When the app issues a redirect to `/page2`, the browser is redirected to `https://example.com/page2` (instead of `.../app/page2`).  Then, when the browser requests the new location, it is not sent to the app, so it returns a 404 or arbitrary page of the main site.

I have tried suggestions given as answers for similar-looking questions, but none of those caused redirects to be handled in this way.

Is this possible with Nginx?  If so, how can this be accomplished?
Or maybe is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Nginx has a `proxy_redirect` feature that will rewrite 3xx responses for you. If you need to do more, such as editing every page on the fly to add `/app` into every hyperlink, you can use the `sub_filter` feature, but it would not be an efficient solution.